# Make images in grid same size

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a Grid that contains 3 rows and 3 columns, where the center grid location is twice the size of the edge columns.

The Grid itself is stretchable and thus doesn't have a fixed size for the rows and columns.

4 Locations in the Grid contain an image with an arrow, I want these 4 arrows to be the same size, but let them grow when the grid itself gets larger. Because the Grid isn't a perfect square the, 4 images aren't exactly the same size and I'm wondering how I can achieve this?

This is how the grid with the images looks like:
[image: Arrows in Grid]

The XAML code is very basic, but I have no idea how to do this. The XAML code looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="/Images/Arrow Up.png" />
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Images/Arrow Left.png"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Images/Light Diodes 2019.png" />
    <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Images/Arrow Right.png"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="/Images/Arrow Down.png"/>
</Grid>
```

I think somehow I have to get the shortest Width or Height and set this Width or Height to the Width or Height of the other 3 images?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have a look at [DecodePixelHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [DecodePixelWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth)

Comment: `Stretch="Uniform"` ??

Comment: Make sure that the Grid is always a "perfect square". Otherwise you need to decide how to stretch the images and what size they should have when the width is greater than the height and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick one of them you think is a good size and bind the height and width of the others to that one.

For example.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="sameSizeImage">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=im1}"   />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=im1}"   />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Name="im1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Source="/Images/AddItem_16x.png" />
    <Image Style="{StaticResource sameSizeImage}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Images/AddItem_16x.png" />
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Images/AddItem_16x.png" />
    <Image Style="{StaticResource sameSizeImage}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Images/AddItem_16x.png"/>
    <Image  Style="{StaticResource sameSizeImage}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="/Images/AddItem_16x.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This solution has a problem if I Bind it to the Top arrow image and the screen gets much heigher as it is wide. But for both 4:3 and 16:9 screens this solution works for me. So I accept it as good enough as it solves my problem :)